# How to make a simple program where both Servlet and JSP together generate HTML file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, response

I wondered if it is possible to send HTML page using both Servlet and JSP. And no, I don't want JSP to do all work by *forwarding* the request from Servlet. I want Servlet to write "hello" and JSP to write "user's name".

This is my try, which failed:

**index.html:**

```
<html><body>
    <form action="MyServlet" method="POST">
        Enter name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <button>Submit name</button>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

**MyServlet.java:**

```
@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.println("hello ");

        RequestDispatcher dispatch = req.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
        dispatch.forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

**test.jsp:**

```
<html><body>
<%= request.getParameter("name") %>
</body></html>
```

After filling my form:

[image]

, I expected to get `hello elephant`. But I only get `elephant`. I tried to put *pw.flush()* inside servlet's code which gave an opposite result - just `hello`.

Now I am stuck, as I don't understand what is wrong. I guess when I flushed a stream, *response* was committed, so rest of code didn't run. But why user didn't get `hello` message when I didn't commit (flush) a stream? Can I even do such a thing as I described? Looks like I am missing some elementary things here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`RequestDispatcher.include(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#include(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)) instead of `forward`. Change

```
dispatch.forward(req, resp);
```

to

```
dispatch.include(req, resp);
```